# How to handle TOUCH UP event after Item long click in android AdapterView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one activity and two fragments
In one fragment I have created an AdapterView, and attached OnItemLongClickListener.
When item long click happens, I am creating another fragment and showing an image

Now what I want is, when I do touch up corresponding to Item long click, dismiss image display fragment
Its something similar to what snapchat does, hold on a list item and display an image, when touch up happens stop image display

I am getting OnItemLongClick and able to launch image display fragment. But not able to come out of it as I am not able to capture TOUCH UP either in activity or in any of fragments

Could you please tell us what is best approach to do this and any sample code?
I googled, but did not find good answer

I just learning android

Thanks